# Сохранение данных в базе postgresql в формате inet и cidr через EF Core

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core

Есть приложение Asp.Net Core WebApi. Есть класс Entity, который содержит свойство типа IPAddress. Хочется его отобразить в базу postgresql в поле с типом "inet". Как описано в документации к библиотеке Npgslq это стандартное отображение. Мне еще необходимо создать уникальный составной индекс, содержащий это поле. В классе контекста для такого отображения использую такой код:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Switch>()
     .Property(e => e.Ipaddr)
     .HasColumnType("inet");
```

Для индекса - такой код:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Switch>()
    .HasIndex(s => new { s.Region, s.Ipaddr }).IsUnique();
```

Если так запустить создание миграции, возникает ошибка
*"Property 'Switch.Ipaddr' cannot be used as a key because it has type 'IPAddress' which does not implement 'IComparable', 'IComparable' or 'IStructuralComparable'. Use 'HasConversion' in 'OnModelCreating' to wrap 'IPAddress' with a type that can be compared."*

Есть добавить конвертер

```
public class IpAddressToInetConverter : ValueConverter<IPAddress, string>
{
    public IpAddressToInetConverter(ConverterMappingHints mappingHints = null)
        : base(
                  ip => ip.ToString(),
                  str => IPAddress.Parse(str),
                  mappingHints)
        {}
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Switch>()
    .Property(e => e.Ipaddr)
    .HasConversion(new IpAddressToInetConverter())
    .HasColumnType("inet");
```

то возникает ошибка

*The 'string' property 'Switch.Ipaddr' could not be mapped to the database type 'inet' because the database provider does not support mapping 'string' properties to 'inet' columns. Consider mapping to a different database type or converting the property value to a type supported by the database using a value converter. See https://aka.ms/efcore-docs-value-converters for more information. Alternately, exclude the property from the model using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.*

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делаю не так. Понимаю, что создание индекса можно добавить в класс миграции в метод Up, но хотелось бы использовать стандартный подход.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23775 - здесь обсуждают эту проблему.

Comment: Большое спасибо за наводку!